# DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener not working in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I've got an app that I've deployed with Azure, and I am trying to get plain vanilla Tracing working

I've gone through all of these articles: 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=diagnosticmonitortracelistener

Here's my role entry point:

```
public class WebRole :RoleEntryPoint {
    public override bool OnStart() {
        if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable) {
            LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyCustomLogs");
            DirectoryConfiguration dirConfig = new DirectoryConfiguration();
            dirConfig.Container = "diagnostics-mycustomlogs-container";
            dirConfig.DirectoryQuotaInMB = localResource.MaximumSizeInMegabytes;
            dirConfig.Path = localResource.RootPath;
            DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagMonitorConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
            diagMonitorConfig.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
            diagMonitorConfig.Directories.DataSources.Add(dirConfig);
            DiagnosticMonitor diagMonitor = DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagMonitorConfig);

            Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
            Trace.AutoFlush = true;
            Trace.WriteLine("Role Starting");
        }
        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

Also put the trace listener in global.asax.cs:

```
        if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable) {
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
            Trace.AutoFlush = true;
        }
```

I've also tried just pasting it directly into web.config

```
 <trace>
     <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, 
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, 
            Version=1.8.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            name="AzureDiagnostics">
            <filter type="" />
</add>
```

This directory gets created in my Azure VM
`C:\Resources\Directory\d63aeab4198d458a9c0b1d0f818e4054.CorpQna.Web.MyCustomLogs`

This is in my `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file:

```
<LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage name="MyCustomLogs" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="10" />
</LocalResources>
```

When I add a `TextWriterTraceListener` in my local Compute Emulator, it works:

```
<trace autoflush="true">
  <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" name="TextWriter"
                             initializeData="c:\trace.log" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

However, this does not work on Azure.  (I suspect permissions?)

I'm at a standstill at this point.  No errors anywhere, but no logs either.  There's no record of the Blob being created in my Blob Store.

Comment: It also doesn't work in the emulator.

Comment: Here is a tutorial http://blog.amtopm.be/2014/07/20/azure-diagnostics-how-to-troubleshoot-your-code/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doug, you are confusing a few different concepts here:

1. Diagnostics Tracing to a file
2. `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener`
3. WAD DirectoryConfiguration

In .NET, diagnostics tracing will write to all of the registered listeners.  The `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener` is a trace listener which essentially writes to the WADLogsTable table in Azure Storage.  `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener` does not write to a local file such as your MyCustomLogs folder.  The WAD `DirectoryConfiguration` will upload files, but this really doesn't have anything to do with .NET diagnostics tracing, unless you are also adding a `TextWriterTraceListener`.

So your code as-is probably works fine, but you are looking in the wrong place for the data.  It won't be in a blob coming from the MyCustomLogs folder, but rather in the WADLogsTable table.  If you want the tracing to also be in the MyCustomLogs folder then you can add another listener of type TextWriterTraceListener pointing to a file in your MyCustomLogs folder.

Comment: I don't have a WADLogsTable table in my TableStorage (or BlobStorage).  Do I need to create that?

Comment: You need to configure WAD Logs in your diagnostics configuration, similar to how you are currently doing the directory configuration.

Comment: Oddly, this just started working a few hours later.  I have no idea why.  Your answer is correct so I've marked it.

Comment: @Doug The table gets created automatically when you deploy with diagnostics turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that in your service configuration, you are using correct storage account for diagnostic.

By default, it is pointing to local dev storage. you may have to change with valid storage account.

```
 <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
```